# Code duplication vs new variable creation

Tags: java, if-statement

Looking for which of the 2 options below is considered good programming practice ?

This is a case of 2 options:
duplicates code,  but does not create new variables / objects

```
if (a > b) {
  calcSum (a, b) + calcDiff(a, b);
} else {
   calcSum (b, a) + calcDiff(b, a);
}
```

vs

does not duplicate code, but creates new variables / objects

```
int big;
int small

if (a > b) {
    big = a;
    small = b;
} else {
    big = a;
    small = b;
} 

calcSum (big, small) + calcDiff(big, small);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter. I prefer the first one since duplicating this much code shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: both way will work, and don't worry too much about object creation.. you can use Math.max/min to resolve this specific problem.. Like `calcSum(Math.max(a,b), Math.min(a,b)) + calcDiff(Math.max(a,b), Math.min(a,b))`

Comment: This is so small code, so there are no problem if you create a new  variable ore dublication code. In general you must create some classes and some function and avoid to dublicate code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what others here have said, I think the second option is preferred.  Duplication of your business logic makes it hard to test and hard to maintain, so you should look for ways to avoid duplicating it.

Another way to do that would be to make it a helper method (`calculateSumPlusDifference(int max, int min)`) and then use it:

```
if (a > b) {
  calculateSumPlusDifference(a, b);
} else {
  calculateSumPlusDifference(b, a);
}
```

This way you still get compact logic around a and b, but you avoid duplicating your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

I would say first option is preferable, as it is both more compact and doesn't create new variables (although that is not really a big concern, it would probably be optimized out).

Also you can use the Math library's min and max methods to do it all on one line if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

They both work. However, you really what to see what's more important. Readability or efficiency? For instance, what some people suggested is using `Math.max` sure, this works. However, its very inefficient. Doing any sort of `Math.` produces a lot of extra unneeded calls. However, its more readable. So We go back down and beg the same question. Readability or efficiency.

Weigh you options, see what is maintainable, readable, and efficient. In the end they obviously both work use YOUR judgement based on the project.

TDLR: if that line of code is going to be needed to be run 100+ times at 1 millisecond go with the second approach if it's only a one time practically linearly ran code go with readability.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like these answers are all missing the point of the question: is it better to duplicate code or to spend memory creating new variables to avoid that duplication?

Well, we can actually put that to the test, can't we.

I wrote a class to run both of your examples with random values of `a` and `b` (between 1 and 10), 100,000,000 times each. The results are actually very revealing:

```
//trial 1
Without Creating Variables: 2.220987762 seconds
vs With Creating Variables: 2.218305816 seconds

//trial 2
Without Creating Variables: 2.215427479 seconds
vs With Creating Variables: 2.220663639 seconds

//trial 3
Without Creating Variables: 2.345803733 seconds
vs With Creating Variables: 2.347936366 seconds
```

Basically, there is practically **no difference** between the two options speed-wise—even when running them one hundred million times.

So, with that established, the option that represents best practice becomes whichever one makes the code more readable and understandable, which is definitely the second.

---

Here's the test class, if you'd like to check for yourself:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int testLoops = 100000000;
        Random rand = new Random();

        //first test
        long startTime1 = System.nanoTime();

        for(int i=0;i<testLoops;i++) {
            int a = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
            int b = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
            int answer;

            if (a > b) {
                answer = calcSum (a, b) + calcDiff(a, b);
            } else {
                answer = calcSum (b, a) + calcDiff(b, a);
            }
        }

        double seconds1 = (double)(System.nanoTime() - startTime1) / 1000000000.0;
        System.out.println("Without Creating Variables: " + seconds1 + " seconds");

        //second test
        long startTime2 = System.nanoTime();

        for(int i=0;i<testLoops;i++) {
            int big;
            int small;
            int a = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
            int b = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
            int answer;

            if (a > b) {
                big = a;
                small = b;
            } else {
                big = a;
                small = b;
            } 
            answer = calcSum (big, small) + calcDiff(big, small);
        }

        double seconds2 = (double)(System.nanoTime() - startTime2) / 1000000000.0;
        System.out.println("   With Creating Variables: " + seconds2 + " seconds");
    }

    public static int calcSum(int a, int b) {
        return a+b;
    }

    public static int calcDiff(int a, int b) {
        return a-b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example that you provided, the difference is negligible, referring to speed as well as readability.

It was obviously "pseudo"-code, otherwise I'd propose a method like

```
void calcBoth(int a, int b) { 
    calcSum(a,b)+calcDiff(a,b); 
}

// Call:
if (a < b) calcBoth(a,b);
else       calcBoth(b,a);
```

Maybe something like this is applicable in your case as well.

Answer (score 0):

The functional programmer purist in me might suggest:

```
public int calc(int a, int b) {
    return (a >= b)
            ? calcSum(a, b) + calcDiff(a, b)
            : calc(b, a);
}
```

At a cost of one recurse you have eliminated **all** temporary variables and succinctly stated your intent.

An efficient compiler may even recognize the tail recursion and substitute the correct tail-recursion-avoidance mechanism.

Comment: Elegant, but in a twisted sort of way.  Unnecessary recursion tends to give me migraines.

Comment: @ajb - Much of the functional programming paradigm **is** using recursion instead of local variables. It may bend your sanity a little but the code analysis becomes super-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the second because it's easier to see your intentions, but I would have just rewritten `calcDiff` so that the order of the parameters don't matter.

```
public int calcDiff(int a, into b) {
    if (a > b)
        return a - b;
    else
        return b - a;
}
```

Presumably the order doesn't matter in `calcSum`.

```
public int calcSum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Then all you need is `calcSum(a, b) + calcDiff(a, b)`.

But as a more general rule I'm not afraid of creating new variables if it improves readability. It doesn't usually make much difference to speed.